# Jquery (fancybox+photoswipe gallery) stop working when W3TC is deactivated

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having a problem on my website.
I use the W3TC wordpress plugin+cloudflare+maxcdn to cache everything on my website.

Now i want to port my site. Since i had isues porting with W3TC turned on i wanted to turn it off and wanted to make a backup. But now all my galleries and fancyboxes stopped working.

Whats going on?
I appreciate any input that could help me solve this, since i don't want to depend on W3TC forever.
Thanks,
Mattis

### ---*EDIT*---

sorry for my unclear question, i will try to clarify.

## 1 Example:

On my homepage sidebar i have a Button named "Contact Us". Once clicked, it opens a popup contact form via the /#fancyboxID-1 command.
However, this only works once W3TC is enabled.
Once disabled, a click on the button will add the /#fancyboxID-1 to the url but Nothing happens.

## 2 Example:

In several subpages I use FIAGallery as a gallery plugin:
This plugin uses Jquery and works fine if W3TC is enabled.
Once disabled, no galleries appear (however the space of the is there, but just empty)

I have played around with W3TC and found out that the Minify settings seem to be responsible for this (once disabled, the problems occur) To be exact it'S the JS minify settings that breaks it once disabled.

### Here are my settings (only the active settings)

---

Rewrite URL structure

HTML minify: enabled
JS minify settings: enabled
CSS minify settings: enabled
Update external files every: 21600 seconds
Garbage collection interval:    21600 seconds

---

I have tried emptying the minify cache but that doesn't show any results.

I hope that's a little clearer, if you need more infos, please ask.
I appreciate all input

Comment: Please add details about what you mean by "stopped working".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CloudFlare's Rocket Loader turned on? This can potentially impact some JavaScript and jQuery & you should turn it off (if on) to see if it fixes the issue. If it dos end up fixing the issue turning it off, please report the bug to us [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/wco-bug-report.html).